# How can I give different labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm comparing the solutions of differential equations using two methods of solving: the analytical and numerical solutions. I would like to label to solid lines with 'Analitical Solution', the dotted lines with 'Numerical Solution' and give each color a different label.

How do I do that?

[image: Graph for exemple]

Here's the code I used to generate the graph

```py
fig1 = plt.scatter(t, I, s=15, label='Numerical')
fig2 = plt.plot(t, it, label='Analytical')
fig3 = plt.scatter(t, S, s=15, label='Numerical')
fig4 = plt.plot(t, st, label='Analytical')
```

Comment: Why don't you change it to `label='Numerical Solution'` instead of `label='Numerical'`.

Comment: It was just an exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, based on ["Composing Custom Legends"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) from the matplotlib documentation:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# -- DATA
t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 40)

# Analytical
a1 = np.tanh(t)
a2 = -np.tanh(t) + 1

# Numerical
n1 = a1 + np.random.randn(*a1.shape) / 50
n2 = a2 + np.random.randn(*a2.shape) / 50

# -- PLOTS
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Colors
clr1 = "C0"
clr2 = "C1"

# Analytical solution
ax.plot(t, a1, color=clr1)
ax.plot(t, a2, color=clr2)

# Numerical solution
ax.scatter(t, n1, color=clr1)
ax.scatter(t, n2, color=clr2)

# Custom legend
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html

legend_elements = [
    Patch(color=clr1, label="Exp. 1"),
    Patch(color=clr2, label="Exp. 2"),
    Line2D(
        [0],
        [0],
        marker="o",
        color="k",
        lw=0,
        label="Numerical",
    ),
    Line2D(
        [0],
        [0],
        color="k",
        label="Analytical",
    ),
]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, ncols=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot with custom legend]